# Unity3D In app purchase Android Non-consumable product, check already purchased

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working on Unity3D InAppPurchase in Android and trying to check the product is already purchased or not.

Ref: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game

Thanks in advance.